# Dynamic Linq "Where statement" with Relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, linq

I'm trying to build a query using Dynamic Linq and a where string statement calculated by myself. For example:

```
List<Publication> results = new List<Publication>();

// Just an example, previously calculated dynamically
string filterQuery = "(Id = 1 and Number = 2)";

IQueryable<Publication> query = db.Publications.Include(i => i.Product);
query = query.Where(filterQuery);

results = query.OrderBy(orderQuery).ToList();
```

This is working great and I get a List of Publications with Products. Now... the question is. How can I make a string statement to get results based on a relation to Product using Dynamic Linq and a string statement?

Something like:

```
string filterQuery = "(Id = 1 and Number = 2 and Products.Id = 1)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research and trying things, this is an easy and friendly way using the same Dynamic Linq library:

```
List<Publication> results = new List<Publication>();

// Just an example, previously calculated dynamically
string filterQuery = "(Id = 1 and Number = 2)";
string filterQueryChildren = "Products.Any(Id == 1)"

IQueryable<Publication> query = db.Publications.Include(i => i.Product).Where(filterQueryChildren);

query = query.Where(filterQuery);

results = query.OrderBy(orderQuery).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you're doing this, but the following should work:

```
List<Publication> results = new List<Publication>();

// Just an example, previously calculated dynamically
string filterQuery1 = "(Id = 1)"
string filterQuery2 = "(Id = 1 and Number = 2)";

IQueryable<Publication> query = db.Publications.
Where(filterQuery1).     
Include(i => i.Product);
query = query.Where(filterQuery2);

results = query.OrderBy(orderQuery).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not working. I get: "The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties".

Comment: No! That's not working. Suppose that Id and Number are attributes of Publications and CategoryId is an attribute for Products. I just want to find Pubications with Id = 1 and Number = 2, and Include Products Where CategoryId (of the product) is, for example 3. Your example gives me: No property or field 'CategoryId' exists in type 'Publication'

Answer (score 0):

To make dynamic LINQ query, you need a library that support it or doing it yourself with [Expression Tree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654263.aspx)

See: [Entity Framework Dynamic Query Library](http://entityframework.net/dynamic-query)

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Eval-Expression.NET](http://eval-expression.net/)

This library allows you to evaluate, compile, and execute code at runtime.

The library also contains extension method for dynamic LINQ

Wiki: [Eval Dynamic LINQ](http://eval-expression.net/linq-dynamic)

Example

```
// using Z.Expressions; // Don't forget to include this.

// The filterQuery must use the C# syntax
string filterQuery = "x.Id == 1 && x.Number = 2";

IQueryable<Publication> query = db.Publications.Include(i => i.Product);
query = query.Where(x => filterQuery);
```

**EDIT:** Answer sub question

> Great but how can I filter by Product?

Entity Framework doesn't support filter in Include method.

However, EF+ do

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

See: [EF+ Query IncludeFilter](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter)

By combining both libraries, you can achieve your desired result:

```
// Extension method must be registered, otherwise the library cannot be aware of which extension method exists!
EvalManager.DefaultContext.RegisterExtensionMethod(typeof (QueryIncludeFilterExtensions));

string where1 = "x.Id == 1 && x.Number == 2";
string where2 = "y.Id == 3";

var left2 = ctx.Publications
    .Where(x => where1)
    .Execute<IQueryable<Publication>>("IncludeFilter(x => x.Product.Where(y => " + where2 + "))")
    .ToList();
```

If you want to try this solution, make sure you download the latest version of Eval-Expression.NET. We just have fixed few min ago an issue we found by trying your scenario.

**EDIT2:** Answer sub question

Here is what I recommend you.

Try the query without our library then try it dynamically after.

That's easier to find the compilation error or what you want to do really.

By example, we probably didn't understand the initial problem correctly and suggested IncludeFilter which you don't want. I assumed you wanted to filter multiple products. However, it looks you only have one product per publication, so the Where clause method obviously doesn't exist.

Maybe this is more what you are looking for:

```
string where1 = "x.Id == 1 && x.Number == 2 && x.Product.Id == 3";

var left2 = ctx.Publications
    .Include(x => x.Product)
    .Where(where1)
    .ToList();
```

So in short, try the query by hardcoding it (without dynamic) then you will know how to use it dynamically after.

Comment: Great but how can I filter by Product? For example: x.Id == 1 && x.Number ==2 are for Publicationes. Can I make something like x.Id == 1 && x.Number ==2 && i.Id = 1 ???? (x for Publications and i for Product)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer Johnathan. So... I get NuGet Packages for Eval-Expression.NET and Entity Framework Plus, I register the library in the Controller's method and I'm ready to go?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Be careful, EF+ is always free but Eval-Expression.NET is free until you reach 50 characters (you should be fine). Let me know if you successfully make it works.

Comment: Sorry but this is not working. I get: Oops! No applicable member has been found for the expression. Then I changed to Product to Products and now the error is: Oops! Select projection are not supported in EF+ Query IncludeFilter. For more information, contact us: info@zzzprojects.com.

Comment: Can you show your expression? We obviously testing it with the code above without a problem. You can contact us directly if you want. It could maybe be easier. Our email is in the error message ;)

Comment: Thank you Johnathan. You have Skype?

Comment: The query is created dynamically but in this case this is the order:
---- 1) IQueryable<Publication> query = db.Publications;
---- 2) query = query.Execute<IQueryable<Publication>>("IncludeFilter(x => x.Products.Where(y => " + secondfilterQuery + "))");
---- 3) var results = query.OrderBy(orderQuery).Skip((page - 1) * limit).Take(limit).ToList();

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have skype yet (for the company). I tried to create an account but it doesn't let us use our company email.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with OrderBy (with string - Dynamic Linq -) and Skip / Take. How can I solve this?

Comment: You are mixing two libraries. Try without the Order to see if the issue is in our library (Eval-Expressions.NET) or Dynamic Linq. We also support OrderBy, see "OrderByDynamic" method. If you can, try to create a small project sample and send it to us, we will check the issue and make it work.